# Logs , methods doesn't work when screen is rotate landscape

Tags: android, landscape-portrait

I'm creating an app, which requires landscape / portrait screen. My problem is, when screen is rotate , the method doesn't work even the logger , so i'm having a hard time trouble shooting things. Anyone who have experience same? What i received in logs after rotation is

```
12-28 00:02:55.897 13039-13039/com.xxx.xxx D/ViewRootImpl: ViewPostImeInputStage processPointer 0
12-28 00:02:55.927 13039-13039/com.xxx.xxx D/ViewRootImpl: ViewPostImeInputStage processPointer 1
```

In here, i'm trying to load a different XML when user is in landscape  or portrait. I'm using this method because, i have additional controls when in landscape mode, and those controls are not available during portrait mode. so i need to call `bindNewControlsLoaded()` method to initialize those controls.

```
@Override
    public void onConfigurationChanged(Configuration newConfig) {
        super.onConfigurationChanged(newConfig);

        if (newConfig.orientation == Configuration.ORIENTATION_LANDSCAPE) {
            setContentView(R.layout.activity_task_page_lan);
            initCreate();
            //im calling this because some controls are newly added
            bindNewControlsLoaded();
        } else if (newConfig.orientation == Configuration.ORIENTATION_PORTRAIT){
            setContentView(R.layout.activity_task_page);
            initCreate();
        }

    }
```

`initCreate` method is a method for portrait , this is use to load common controls. while additional controls are called in the `bindNewControlsLoaded();`

In my manifest `android:configChanges="orientation|screenSize"`

Comment: Please add Logs with newConfig inside onConfigurationChanged after super. And show your activity declaration.

Answer (score 0):

By default android recreate activity on rotate so you can do it without `onConfigurationChanged` at all just use [resource qualifiers](https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/resources/providing-resources.html#table2) . In your case just move `activity_task_page_lan.xml` to res/layout-land/ folder and rename to `activity_task_page.xml`.

But if you really want to handle this case with your code and prevent activity recreation you should add `android:configChanges="orientation"` to activity declaration.

Comment: android:configChanges="orientation|screenSize" i have something like this in my manifest already. Yes im handling it on my own because , i loaded some additional controls during landscape mode.

Comment: Why you don't want just recreate activity on rotation and write conditional logic for additional controls in onCreate?